# How to remove references that are automatically added in web.config

Tags: visual-studio-2005

All aplications in Visual Studio 2005 in my machine add n references automaticlly. How do I fix that?

Comment: I'm confused.  You can edit your web.config, so you can change it however you like?  Or do you just want VS 2005 to not add anything to your web.config to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was in System.Web.Extensions 3.5, now I changed to System.Web.Extensions 1.6 and fix the problem.

Thanks for the help.